# How to create link to another slide with VSTO (powerpoint)?

Tags: vsto, slideshow, powerpoint

I'm struggling to find a way to create a link to another slide with VSTO for powerpoint, does anybody know how to do it ? No way to find any solution on the internet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translate this from VBA to VSTO and you should be good to go.  Pass it references to the shape you want to apply the link on, and the slide you want to link to.

```vb
Sub MakeLink(osh As Shape, oLinkTargetSlide As Slide)

    With osh.ActionSettings(1)
        .Action = ppActionHyperlink
        .Hyperlink.Address = ""
        .Hyperlink.SubAddress = oLinkTargetSlide.SlideID & "," & oLinkTargetSlide.SlideIndex & ","
    End With
End Sub
```

You might instead want to declare `oSh` as `Object`; then you could pass the `Sub` either a shape or a `TextRange` to apply the link to.